# Doubts regarding constructing an emergency light

Tags: voltage, led, batteries, amperage

I have made an emergency light using 12v LED strip (3 LED's on the strip) with a 9v battery, its run time was 10hrs plus. My doubt is if I can use the same setup with a 12v 200 Ah battery, what will I encounter? Is this even possible?

Comment: Since the strip is designed to operate with 12VDC input, no problem with operating a battery. You may have a bit higher brightness, btw.

Comment: Also, 9V batteries typically have ~0.5Ah of capacity so you'll get a much longer life, too.  You won't get 4,000 hours (10hr*200Ah/0.5Ah) since you're drawing more current at 12V, but you may get somewhere around 3,000 hours.

Comment: Woah ! Thank you so much . I shall give it a try soon .

Answer (score 1):

Higher current draw meaning a brighter led strip, but with a larger capacity equalling a longer run time. Unless you short something out, there is no difference in usage. A 200 Ah battery can provide a nasty kick if you short it out.